# Change Facebook iframe style css

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, comments

i'm in a html + javascript course
and i got an interesting exercise which i can't find a solution of maybe you could help

there is a site made by ebay : 
http://www.ebay.com/gds/Cool-Kitchen-Gadgets-/10000000202435634/g.html
which has a plugin by facebook where you can insert your comments on each product

what i need to do is changing the style of the comments section , for example the pictures should be 25px * 25px , the text should look better etc.

all these can be changed from the inspect element section but can't be change via a dedicated  tag since it's an external iframe

could you please assist ?
i gueess it has to be done from an javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Recognize the class names for the comments section etc. (by manual inspection)
2. On page load, write a Javascript method to override existing css. it has to be done **after** the facebook widgets are loaded i.e. `document.OnLoad`.

That said, let us leave the coding part (and figuring out the code) to you, because DIY.
I would recommend using JQuery though, friend!

Comment: "because DIY"? -1. You haven't answered the question. It's not upto you to tell OP to do it himself. If you don't like his style of questioning, comment in the comment boxes available. SO isn't about "leaving the coding part".